# The program crashes when I convert String to Int in Edittext

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.testapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.testapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        binding.btplus.setOnClickListener {
            val text:String = binding.editText0.text.toString()
             : = .();
            val text1:String = binding.editText1.text.toString()
             : = .();
        }
    }
}
```

- The program works fine, but as soon as I add the terms highlighted in bold, it immediately crashes after starting, how to fix it?
  I already tried to write in one line ( val str:Int = Integer.parseInt(num_page.getText().toString().trim()); If you write in OnCreate will also not work

Stack Trace:

```
2022-08-18 14:12:43.483 14404-14404/com.example.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 14404
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.onResume$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:21)
        at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$rQfcS0awJWodqb-rjntyTgMojSM(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.testapp.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-08-18 14:12:43.501 14404-14404/com.example.testapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14404 SIG: 9
```

Comment: try adding `.trim()` after both `toString()`s

Comment: didn't help, keeps crashing :(

Comment: Please add stacktrace

Comment: well, the crash says at least one of the edittexts is empty. Your code only works when both contain numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have reason clearly written in stack trace: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Your edittexts are empty. You have to handle it somehow. I see you are using Kotlin so try this:

```
val number = binding.editText0
    .text
    .toString()
    .trim()
    .toIntOrNull()
    ?: 0
```

It will trim your string first (to make sure there are no spaces), then try to convert it to int and in case of failure it will evaluate to 0.

Comment: Of course you can remove elvis operator and you will have null that you will need to handle somehow :)

Comment: it is strange why it enters that the edittexts are empty, I enter information in two edittexts

Comment: maybe you are clicking btplus before you enter numbers there?

Comment: first I enter the numbers in the fields, then I click bplus

Comment: my line must be like this to fix this proplem?                                                   
 val text:String = binding.editText0.text.toString().trim().toIntOrNull() ?: 0

Comment: You have wrong type. Use Int or let it assign type automatically. Let me know if now it works.

Comment: override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        binding.btplus.setOnClickListener {
            val text = binding.editText0.text.toString().trim().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
            val text1 = binding.editText1.text.toString().trim().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
            val textint:Int = Integer.parseInt(text.toString());
            val textint1:Int = Integer.parseInt(text1.toString());
            //binding.result.setText(textint)
           binding.textView.setText(textint)
        }
    }
now my code look like this, but the app keeps crashing :*(

Comment: @x1oto you don't need the `Integer.parseInt` lines, the answer posted here already parses and produces an `Int` (using `toIntOrNull`, which is the way you should do it in Kotlin). If you're still getting the same crash (`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`) then the `EditText`s you're reading from *are* empty, so something else is going on. Either you're referencing the wrong ones (we'd need to see your layout XML) or there's multiple copies getting inflated, or something - there's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've posted!